# Woocommerce Display Products in category different page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, e-commerce

I want to display all the products in a certain category on a different page to the shop page.

How can I do this in a way that the page I want to display it on will be editable and has a banner and information, etc.? Similar to the way the woocommerce display products widget works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could use a shortcode `[product_category category="your_category_name"]`.
For more infos [see here](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/).